# Firebase user permissions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Being relatively new to Firebase I'm getting my head round the permissions, vital if you don't want unauthorised manipulation in javascript. I have the very basic rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

This means I can set a user/email which has to login at client end to see or do any CRUD functions with the data. What I want to do is allow users to register and only edit or delete anything they have posted themselves, so read any questions and feedback and post their own, but can not tamper with anything they haven't posted themselves.

Comment: Read the [Firebase documentation on securing user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security). I'd recommend spending some more time in the docs, since it answers this and many similar questions.

Comment: OK I'm getting somewhere with the User permissions with auth.uid. Took a while to figure the question key has to match the uid instead of the -Kblahblahblah.